# How to publish event to angular js 1.4 from spring boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, sockjs

**Scenario:**
Client(angular js 1.4) will call Rest endpoint to get data, the server(spring boot) will process the list of files and will return accurate data. To process the list of files, the server will take time depending on the number of files. so I have implements STOMP notification as to send a notification to the client saying "List of files have been processed and here is the bunch of files(result)".

**Issue:** 
Stomp connection is established successfully and client also gets subscribed, but when the server publishes the events, client is not able to receive.

Below is my code snippet:

WebSocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); // Enables a simple in-memory broker
  }
}
```

SocketController.java

```
   @Controller
    public class SocketController {
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
        public String sendMessage() {
            LOGGER.info("====> chatMessage()");
            return "List updated successfully";
        }
    }
```

main.js

```
connect() {
                var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
                var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("socket: ", socket);
                console.log("stompClient: ", stompClient);

                stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
                        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);   
                        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', function (payload) {
                        console.log("payload: ", payload);
                        var message = JSON.parse(payload.body);
                        console.log("message: ", message);
                        });
                    }, function (error) {
                     console.log("onError() called");
                                console.log("error: ",error);
                    });
        };
```

Scripts used:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
```

connect() method of main.js is called on button click. Probably there is an issue regarding scope I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SimpMessagingTemplate to convert and send messages to the specific topic.

```
@Controller
public class SocketController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocketController.class);

    @Autowired private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        LOGGER.info("====> sendMessage:");
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/public", message);
    }
}
```